# Android: can I programmatically extend wifi range?

Tags: android

I realize that it would probably require boosting antenna power and thus reduce battery life but, if I am prepared to accept that, can I programmatically extend wifi range?

I don't find anything at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to extend wifi range, as you don't have the hardware controls at such a low level to do that. You might try looking at the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), but I still doubt it.

This was a very interesting question, and I've looked around a bit more and you really can't. Sorry!

Comment: +1 As I feared, thanks. I'll leave it a day or two in case someone knows better, but otherwise you get awarded the answer. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 2):

not possible with software, however, sometimes, you can open the phone (this will void your warranty) and the main power contributor may have a switch for different wattages, if its not set to the highest, do so, and it will increase your range, a lot of phones don't have this, but if your lucky, you can do that.